# Eslint cache ignored in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, eslint

I'm trying to implement eslint caching in our project. While it works just fine on the local machine, it doesn't work in the gitlab lint stage.

Local: [image]

Gitlab: [image]

As can be seen from screenshots, gitlab doesn't use the cache.

package.json:

```json
 "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "lint": "npm-run-all lint:eslint lint:ts lint:stylelint",
    "lint:eslint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --cache --cache-strategy content -c .eslintrc.js .",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "npm run lint:eslint -- --fix",
    "lint:ts": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint:stylelint": "./node_modules/.bin/stylelint --cache --config stylelint.config.js .",
    "lint:stylelint:fix": "npm run lint:stylelint -- --fix",
    "test": "npm run cypress:start",
    "test-ci": "npm run cypress:start-ci",
    "test-e2e": "start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:3000 cypress open --e2e",
    "cypress:start": "RESPOND_MOCK_RESULT_DELAY=1 cypress open --component",
    "cypress:start-ci": "RESPOND_MOCK_RESULT_DELAY=1 cypress run --component --browser chrome",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9000 --no-version-updates",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -c .storybook",
    "postinstall": "husky install",
    "clean-tsc": "rimraf tmp"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{vue, ts}": [
      "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ./config/linters/eslint-config.js --max-warnings=0"
    ],
    "**/*.ts": [
      "bash -c tsc --noEmit"
    ],
    "**/*.scss": [
      "./node_modules/.bin/stylelint --config stylelint.config.js"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
      "post-commit": "clean-tsc"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.15",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.15",
    "@nuxt/babel-preset-app": "2.15.6",
    "@nuxt/types": "2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.13.6",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "1.4.1",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "6.3.8",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "6.3.8",
    "@storybook/vue": "6.3.8",
    "@types/crypto-js": "4.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.178",
    "@types/node": "16.7.8",
    "@types/swiper": "5.4.3",
    "@types/vuelidate": "0.7.15",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.22.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.22.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.3.0",
    "anychart": "8.11.0",
    "app-root-path": "3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
    "css-loader": "5.2.7",
    "cypress": "10.10.0",
    "cypress-multi-reporters": "1.6.1",
    "date-fns": "2.28.0",
    "dotenv-flow": "3.2.0",
    "element-ui": "2.15.9",
    "eslint": "7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "14.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "1.1.5",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "7.9.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.4",
    "flag-icons": "6.0.3",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "6.2.12",
    "husky": "8.0.1",
    "iso-country-currency": "0.6.0",
    "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
    "lint-staged": "10.5.4",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "lvovich": "2.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "nuxt": "2.15.8",
    "nuxt-property-decorator": "2.9.1",
    "postcss-easy-media-query": "1.0.0",
    "postcss-inline-svg": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-scss": "2.1.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.2",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "10.2.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "1.14.0",
    "storybook-addon-designs": "6.1.0",
    "storybook-vue-router": "1.0.7",
    "style-loader": "1.2.1",
    "stylelint": "13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-rational-order": "0.1.2",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "22.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "4.1.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "swiper": "5.3.8",
    "ts-loader": "8.2.0",
    "ts-node": "10.2.1",
    "typescript": "3.9.9",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "vue": "2.6.14",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "4.1.1",
    "vue-bem-cn": "1.1.1",
    "vue-click-outside": "1.1.0",
    "vue-eslint-parser": "7.6.0",
    "vue-inline-svg": "2.1.0",
    "vue-inputmask": "0.2.1",
    "vue-loader": "15.9.3",
    "vue-popperjs": "2.3.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "9.1.2",
    "vue2-datepicker": "3.10.4",
    "vuelidate": "0.7.6",
    "vuex": "3.6.2",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "1.2.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "3.2.1",
    "webpack": "4.46.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.15"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@2.4.2"
```

gitlab stage output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.9.1 (bd40e3da)
  on Runner1 cEWYset_
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image node:16 ...
Pulling docker image node:16 ...
Using docker image sha256:147af8719073e2afc51f6c60792867b0329ef40b2e76dbf6dedd9afc85b510f3 for node:16 with digest node@sha256:6d592fdb89fccdeb880d14f30bf139b8a755f33b376f025b70e50ac5547c8ccf ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner-cewyset-project-17-concurrent-0 via runner1...
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 1...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/my_project/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out ce13aedf as issue/NBOM-682...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:147af8719073e2afc51f6c60792867b0329ef40b2e76dbf6dedd9afc85b510f3 for node:16 with digest node@sha256:6d592fdb89fccdeb880d14f30bf139b8a755f33b376f025b70e50ac5547c8ccf ...
$ yarn install --immutable --immutable-cache --skip-builds
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
Resolution step
00:00
➤ YN0002: │ @nuxt/types@npm:2.15.8 doesn't provide webpack (p1a032), requested by sass-loader
➤ YN0002: │ @nuxt/typescript-build@npm:2.1.0 [7e7d0] doesn't provide webpack (p59f68), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ @nuxt/typescript-build@npm:2.1.0 [7e7d0] doesn't provide webpack (pc05f7), requested by ts-loader
➤ YN0002: │ @storybook/core@npm:6.3.8 [2e4c8] doesn't provide webpack (p4aa58), requested by @storybook/core-client
➤ YN0002: │ @storybook/csf-tools@npm:6.3.8 doesn't provide @babel/core (p4793d), requested by @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
➤ YN0002: │ @storybook/csf-tools@npm:6.3.8 doesn't provide @babel/core (p197f9), requested by @babel/preset-env
➤ YN0002: │ @storybook/vue@npm:6.3.8 [7e7d0] doesn't provide typescript (p6db5c), requested by ts-loader
➤ YN0060: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. provides @storybook/addon-actions (p35c9b) with version 6.3.8, which doesn't satisfy what storybook-vue-router requests
➤ YN0002: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. doesn't provide @storybook/addons (p8488a), requested by storybook-vue-router
➤ YN0002: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. doesn't provide mocha (pdf97f), requested by cypress-multi-reporters
➤ YN0002: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. doesn't provide vue-class-component (p9513b), requested by vue-property-decorator
➤ YN0002: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. doesn't provide vue-router (p4a39c), requested by storybook-vue-router
➤ YN0002: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. doesn't provide vue-template-compiler (pb9003), requested by @storybook/vue
➤ YN0002: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. doesn't provide vue-template-compiler (pb2b16), requested by @vue/test-utils
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt-property-decorator@npm:2.9.1 doesn't provide vue (pbab38), requested by vue-class-component
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt-property-decorator@npm:2.9.1 doesn't provide vue (p28c57), requested by vue-property-decorator
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt-property-decorator@npm:2.9.1 doesn't provide vue (pfcb4b), requested by vuex-class
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt-property-decorator@npm:2.9.1 doesn't provide vue (p81681), requested by vuex-module-decorators
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt-property-decorator@npm:2.9.1 doesn't provide vuex (p77ea5), requested by vuex-class
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt-property-decorator@npm:2.9.1 doesn't provide vuex (p14b0f), requested by vuex-module-decorators
➤ YN0002: │ nuxt@npm:2.15.8 doesn't provide consola (p2d844), requested by @nuxt/components
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:11.0.4 doesn't provide typescript (p79ddf), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ react-dev-utils@npm:11.0.4 doesn't provide webpack (p2af19), requested by fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
➤ YN0002: │ storybook-addon-designs@npm:6.1.0 doesn't provide react (p0b861), requested by @figspec/react
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 497ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
Fetch step
00:01
➤ YN0013: │ 2162 packages were already cached
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 1s 220ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
Link step
➤ YN0062: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.3.2#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.3.2&hash=11e9ea The platform linux is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0062: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.13#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.13&hash=11e9ea The platform linux is incompatible with this module, link skipped.
➤ YN0006: │ aplgo-backoffice@workspace:. lists build scripts, but is referenced through a soft link. Soft links don't support build scripts, so they'll be ignored.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 33s 176ms
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 35s 508ms
$ DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine yarn lint:eslint
2022-10-21T05:51:57.876Z eslint:cli-engine Lint /builds/aplgo/my-project/accordion-block/index.ts
...
```

gitlab lint.yml
[image]

I hoped that `--cache-strategy content` will work correctly after git clone in CI.. Maybe I missed smth?

Comment: This is not meant as an answer, just a step in your own exploration here: you're telling the GitLab runner to create a docker instance and run eslint within the docker instance. What do you do with the cache files eslint creates while it's inside that docker instance? Do you discard them when you terminate the docker instance? (Meanwhile, note that *Git* is not involved at all here. Git just provides commits that provide files.)

Comment: My bad, seems like I misunderstood the documentation:(

Answer (score 0):

In Gitlab CI, the files or directories that you want to be cached needs to be specified under the `cache` key so they are persisted. Otherwise, any new job starts from scratch.

Here is how you can do it.

```
Check code-style:
  stage: test
  cache:
    - key: eslintcache # you can name it anything
      paths:
        - .eslintcache # the file to cache
      policy: pull-push
  script:
    - npm run lint
```

In this example, the `key` is static, so the same cache would be used in this job across all branches. But if you want to use the cache in only specific branches, you can use [Gitlab CI/CD variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) to achieve that.

PS. The cache-strategy for ESLint needs to be `content`. It doesn't work with the default `metadata` strategy.